# How do I know if the service is expecting a string array?

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have been given wsdl without docs.

It has these two

```
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <FL>?</FL>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <Mp>?</Mp>
```

and when converted to c# it returns

```
 public string[] FL {
        get {
            return this.flfield;
        }
        set {
            this.flfield = value;
        }
    }

    public string[] Mp {
        get {
            return this.mpField;
        }
        set {
            this.mpField = value;
        }
    }
```

Now my questions is that what does it expect from me to pass? The string array ? truly?

Comment: When I tell you „Give me zero or more of something.“ do you know what you have to give me exactly? - No, because there is no definition of something (could be anything). string is one of this anything and could be right or wrong, we do not know

Comment: Yeah but when converted, it appeared as string[]

Comment: also the FL and Mp itself are strings

Comment: Within an XML everything is a string ... everything has to be serialized into a string to be represented in XML - there is no information about what exactly (structure) is expected between `<FL>` and `</FL>` - you have to ask the ones responsible for the service

Comment: they are not available but I did something like this and it worked,  Dim listMp As New List(Of String)
            listMp.Add(TextBox3.Text)
            MYObj.Mp = listMp.ToArray()

Comment: so it means it will work for more value if working for one